# how to concat two data frames with different column names in pandas? - python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'x':[4,5,6],'y':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10,11,12],'x':[13,14,15],'y':[16,17,18]})
```

I'm trying to merge the two data frames using the keys from the `df1`. I think I should use `pd.merge` for this, but I how can I tell pandas to place the values in the `b` column of `df2` in the `a` column of `df1`. This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
    a   x   y
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
3   10  13  16
4   11  14  17
5   12  15  18
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the column for `df2` so it aligns:

```
In [92]:
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={'b':'a'})], ignore_index=True)

Out[92]:
    a   x   y
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
3  10  13  16
4  11  14  17
5  12  15  18
```

similarly you can use `merge` but you'd need to rename the column as above:

```
In [103]:
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'b':'a'}),how='outer')

Out[103]:
    a   x   y
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
3  10  13  16
4  11  14  17
5  12  15  18
```

Comment: Nice one. You saved my day

Answer (score 27):

Use numpy to concatenate the dataframes, so you don't have to rename all of the columns (or explicitly ignore indexes).  `np.concatenate` also works on an arbitrary number of dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.concatenate( (df1.values, df2.values), axis=0 ) )
df.columns = [ 'a', 'x', 'y' ]
df
```

Answer (score 6):

You can rename columns and then use functions `append` or `concat`:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
# pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

You can also concatenate both dataframes with `vstack` from `numpy` and convert the resulting ndarray to dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1, df2]), columns=df1.columns)
```