# Issues using "pd.concat". Two dataframes are doubling in column length and with "NaN" values instead of merging rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

The goal is to essentially combine the two databases and keep the alphabetical headers from the Tk1P dataframe while integrating the data from the Tk1L dataframe.  Unfortunately I am getting this unintended result when trying to merge.  Please see the link below the code to giphy for the output screen which shows both databases and the concat result.  If anyone has ideas it would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance.

```
Tk1D = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\DF2.xlsx',1)
Tk1D = Tk1D.dropna()
Tk1D.drop(Tk1D.columns[[0, 1, 10]], inplace=True, axis=1)
#print("Tk1D: ", len(Tk1D), 'X', len(Tk1D.columns))
print('----------------------------------------------------------')

Tk1P = Tk1D.drop(['NT', 'PT'], axis=1)
Tk1P = Tk1P.drop(Tk1P.index[2:10035])
print(Tk1P)
print("Tk1P: ", len(Tk1P), 'X', len(Tk1P.columns))
print('----------------------------------------------------------')


Tk1L = xw.Book('C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\DF2.xlsx').sheets[1]
Tk1L = Tk1L.range('A2:N2').value
Tk1L = pd.DataFrame([Tk1L])
Tk1L.drop(Tk1L.columns[[0, 1, 10, 11, 12]], inplace=True, axis=1)
print(Tk1L)
print("Tk1L: ", len(Tk1L), 'X', len(Tk1L.columns))
print('----------------------------------------------------------')


TKP = pd.DataFrame(Tk1P.iloc[0]).transpose()
TKP.columns = Tk1P.columns
TKP = pd.concat([Tk1L, TKP], ignore_index=True)

print(TKP)
```

[Giphy Dataframe and Concat Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDskI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to concat two data frames with different column names in pandas? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925354/how-to-concat-two-data-frames-with-different-column-names-in-pandas-python)

Comment: @MacOS Unfortunately this does not solve this issue.  Also the larger implementation is a situation where the columns are in the hundreds and they can change periodically.  So manually entering column headers wont be a long term solution.  But appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: I see. I have updated my answer. Please check it ou! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your ouput it seems that you concat the `df`along the columns axis.

Try `append` instead of `concat`.

```py
Tk1L.append(TKP)
```

**EDIT**

Look at the following two lines

```py
TKP.columns = Tk1P.columns
TKP = pd.concat([Tk1L, TKP], ignore_index=True)
```

You set the **column names** of `TKP` equal to the **column names** of `Tk1P` in the first line. But in the second line, you append `TKP` to `Tk1L` **(!)**. So the follwing should solve your problem

```py
TKP.columns = Tk1L.columns
TKP = pd.concat([Tk1L, TKP], ignore_index=True)
```

I therefore guess that you simply mixed this up.

**EDIT TWO**

There is another problem in your code.

```py
TKP = pd.DataFrame(Tk1P.iloc[0]).transpose()
```

The `transpose` likely messes things up. `Tk1P` is a *2 x 9* data frame. But when you transpose this, you get a *9 x 2* data frame. So, if you delete the `transpose`, you should be fine.

**EDIT THREE**

If you want alphatic column names, do

```py
TKP.columns = Tk1P.columns
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I try this I get the Tk1P output (shown in the giphy) but just with column 0 remaining and column 1 dropped.  No change in values.

Comment: @Trident1000: I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Just gave this a go.  This results in the exact same output in my post unfortunately (2 rows x 18 columns).  This issue is very tricky.

Comment: I just realized that you `transpose` your data frame. This is likely the issue.

Comment: Yeah but if I take that out then I will get "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 9 elements".

Comment: Ok we are getting closer here.  This is the first time I have been able to merge the two database value rows.  Your suggestion to change "TKP.columns = Tk1P.columns" to "TKP.columns = Tk1L.columns" worked.  However, the headers are numbers and not alphabetic.

Comment: My code is the exact same in my original post except with the Tk1P to Tk1L edit.  All looks good, just need the header to go back to alphabetic and not numbers.

Comment: You then have to simply overwrite the column names of TKP with the ones from Tk1P, if I'm not mistaken. Please check out my edit. I'm glad it worked, BTW.

Comment: Absolutely.  My next thing to figure out.  Shouldnt be too hard.  Havent taken one dataframe headers and used it to overwrite anothers yet though.

Comment: HAH, I just reversed the code to "Tk1L.columns = TKP.columns" and now I get alphabetic headers.  All solved

Comment: Drop a bitcoin address and Ill be happy to give you a tip (not sure if thats allowed here but whatever).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Trident1000 haha. I'm not surry if it is allowed here, but I'm cool, thank you. Just consider to give my answer an UpVote and mark it as the correct solution and I'm more than happy. I'm happy that you fixed your problem! :)

Comment: Just marked it correct.  Painfully I dont have enough reputation to upvote you apparently.  Thanks again and take care.