# How to make the union of two df that have different column names

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas  i have two dataframe both has 4 column but different column name.
Eventhough the column names differ they actually contains the same info.

If i try to concat them pandas make a 8 column df, but i want it to stay for column.

```
df1
     A B C D
     1 2 3 4
     5 6 7 8

df2
     D  F  G  H
     7  8  9 10
    11 12 13 14
```

The result I want is : DF3

```
 A  B   C   D
 1  2   3   4
 5  6   7   8
 7  8   9   10
 11 12  13  14
```

Could you please let me know how to make the union of DF1 and DF2 like this ?

Thanks

Comment: `df1.append(df2.rename(columns={'D':'A', 'F':'B', 'G':'C', 'H':'D'}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to concat two data frames with different column names in pandas? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925354/how-to-concat-two-data-frames-with-different-column-names-in-pandas-python)

Comment: At first glance I though it does not but  I am mistaken you are actually right .  This works too. Also some awsome answer arrived on this question as well . 

Thank you, and thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below:

```py
df2.columns = df1.columns
df3 = df1.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns = dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns)))])
Out[16]: 
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
0   7   8   9  10
1  11  12  13  14
```

Comment: But this will only work if the indices of columns from df1 and df2 are the same, I would suggest creating the dictionary manually @András Czeitner, until and unless you are 100% that the indices of all the columns from both the data frames are exactly matching.

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the columns in df2 to match df1, then append the dataframe

```
names = df1.columns.values.tolist()

df2 = df2.rename(columns = names, inplace = True)

df3 = df1.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the column names of df2 to be the same as df1, and apply `.append()`. Finally reset the index.

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
df3 = df1.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
```